# Apache Hide Specific File Types from Web

Tags: apache-2.2, php, web-server, .htaccess, files

I have a repository of files with .php, .sh, and .txt extensions which gets checked out to the web directory of my server (/var/www).  I need the .php files to be able to be reached by typing in a url but I want the .sh and .txt files only to be accessible internally -- meaning they can be read and run by php or a cron but never by a user typing in their url.  How can I do this on apache?  Do I need to set the permissions of the files to something or mess with the .htaccess or do something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *correct* way of doing this is by moving the files *out* of your document root -- you're just a configuration failure away from data leakage, which is never a fun place to be.  Look at any modern web application framework for an example and execution.

However, to do this in Apache you just use a `LocationMatch` directive in the appropriate context:

```
<LocationMatch \.sh$>
    order deny,allow
    deny from all
</Location>
```

Comment: Ok thank you.  The reason it wasn't like to begin with was it was part of a repository which I had to checkout to the web directory but maybe there is a way around this too... I also found that I can change the premission for 'others' and it can still run the shell scripts but not show them.